# Vuejs: How to reset Input boxes inside Vue Component

Tags: vue.js

Whenever I open the component, the previous information that I've typed still remains in the Input Boxes. I have three input box. One is not inside a form tag and the other two are inside a form tag. How do we clear the Input Boxes when I open the component? I tried using `this.form.reset();` but it does not work.

```js
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Scan Item</label>
                    <input type="search" class="form-control is-warning" id="exampleSearchItemBarcode" placeholder="Item Barcode"
                           @keyup.enter="searchloanItem"
                           v-model="itemvmodel"
                           autocomplete="off">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- right column -->
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card-body">

                <form @submit.prevent="createLoan">
                    <div class="form-group" v-for="loanpatron in loanpatrons" :key="loanpatron.id">
                        <input type="text" name="patron_id"
                               v-model="form.patron_id"
                                class="form-control text-uppercase"
                                :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('patron_id') }"
                               autocomplete="off">
                        <has-error :form="form" field="patron_id"></has-error>
                    </div>


                    <!-- textarea -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date Loaned</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input v-model="form.dateloaned" type="date" name="dateloaned" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('dateloaned') }"
                                   data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="dd/mm/yyyy" data-mask="" im-insert="false">
                        </div>
                        <has-error :form="form" field="dateloaned"></has-error>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script> 
          export default {
            mounted() {
              this.form.reset();
            }
         }
        </script>
```

Comment: that's because your component does not get destroyed somehow. The containing component should wrap this one in a v-if or something (a v-show will only hide it I think)

Comment: form.reset does not work because data still holds the values. You can manually call `this.form.dateloaned = null` etc ... or you  need replace new initial data for component